# Ingenico POS NFC UID wrong encoding

Tags: nfc, smartcard, reader

Our team develop POS solution for NFC cards on Ingenico devices.
What we use to read the card:

---

```
/* Open the MIFARE driver  */
int  ClessMifare_OpenDriver (void);
Return value: OK

 /*Wait until a MIFARE contactless card is detected*/      
 int ClessMifare_DetectCardsEx (unsigned char nKindOfCard, unsigned int *pNumOfCards, unsigned int nTimeout);
 Return value: OK


/*Retrieve the type of the MIFARE card and its UID */
int ClessMifare_GetUid (unsigned char nCardIndex, unsigned char *pKindOfCard, unsigned char *pUidLength, unsigned char *pUid);
```

Return Value:

```
Paramater2:
 pKindOfCard(Type of cards)
 Card1:    CL_B_UNDEFINED
 Card2:    CL_B_UNDEFINED
 Card3:    CL_B_UNDEFINED
 Card4:    CL_MF_CLASSIC
 Paramater4:   pUid ( UID of the card)
 Card1:   "\004Br\302\3278\200"  
 Card2:   "\004\333\354y\342\002\200"
 Card3:   "\004s\247B\344?\201"  
 Card4:   "\016\310d\301"
```

---

But in real life we expect:

```
Card1   044272c2d73880
Card2   0ec864c1
Card3   0473a742e43f81
Card4   04dbec79e20280
```

From Android NFC readers we get correct numbers, but from POS its quite different as a output from Ingenico POS. What we need to do to get this number in hex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually seeing the right UIDs here. There is just a representation issue you are not expecting.  Return values you are quoting are C strings with octal escaping for non-printable characters.  `\nnn` is octal representation of a byte.

In the value `"\004s\247B\344?\201"`, you have `\004`, byte of value 0x04, followed by printable character `s`, of value 0x73, followed by `\247`, value 0xa7, etc.

You can convert to hex for debugging with python for example:

```
$ python2
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.b2a_hex("\004Br\302\3278\200")
'044272c2d73880'
>>> binascii.b2a_hex("\004\333\354y\342\002\200")
'04dbec79e20280'
>>> binascii.b2a_hex("\004s\247B\344?\201")
'0473a742e43f81'
>>> binascii.b2a_hex("\016\310d\301")
'0ec864c1'
```

But overall, data is here.